# Transition to Intermediate(ish) Rails Development

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I hope you're all doing well. I'm fairly new to Rails, and even newer to Stack Overflow. To illustrate my experience with programming, I just finished up my first year of college, which included the classes Intro to Programming, and Data Structures. I feel that I have a good understanding of most programming concepts. I did well in my compsci classes, and I plan to major in computer science.

This summer, I am working as a software engineering intern for an independent consultant. I have access to several full-scale projects, but whenever I try to understand them, I am too quickly overwhelmed with new material.

Working with Rails is a new ballpark. I've followed several rails tutorial sites, including Treehouse, Codeschool, and railstutorial.org. I've done quite a bit of other research, in order to answer my specific questions. I feel that I have a good understanding of MVC architecture and TDD. If I had to pinpoint a weakness, it would be routing and controller methods.

My question is what to learn next. Treehouse, Codeschool, and railstutorial.org were very helpful with the basics, but I am uncertain of what to learn next. What are the some important topics for someone of my level to be learning?

Comment: Hi Mike, I don't think your question is quite right for StackOverflow (hence the close vote), but you might be better off asking on the Rails or Ruby mailing lists. If you really want to understand web dev, then understanding HTTP in general will serve you well regardless of the language and framework, even reading about status codes and headers on Wikipedia will help. All the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best thing to do is to create an app. Think of something that would help people, and build it. Don't make it too big to start with, but have a menu on the home page, and other pages linked from the menus.

As you build it in Rails, you'll hit problems like, wow, how do I do that, or it just doesn't work. And then you'll look for answers in the Rails tutorial, on StackOverflow, etc.

That's how I moved from learning to doing.

Hope that helps.